# Require wordpress login to view Page

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication

I have a WordPress page that is only meant for the staff of the company to see. Using the functions.php file I am trying to put the page behind a login wall. This is what I have so far.

```
function shortcode_needLogin() {
    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        auth_redirect();
    }
```

1. Is the user logged in? (Yes = View page) (No = Redirect to WP Login)
2. After successful login redirect back to the page.

I just need help to make this apply to only one page "home/restricted/"

I have read through several other posts but they all restrict the entire website. Not just one page. This is the one post that got me the closest to what I was looking for:

- [How do I require authorization / login to view a specific set of
  posts / pages?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/71960/how-do-i-require-authorization-login-to-view-a-specific-set-of-posts-pages)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use the [template_redirect](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_redirect/) hook and the WordPress [Conditional Tags](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/conditional-tags/) to check for the page and if the user is logged-in before redirecting to log in.

For example, try adding this code to your theme's functions.php file:

```
<?php

function my_restricted_page() {
    if ( is_page('restricted') && ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $redirect_url = get_permalink();
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url( $redirect_url ), 302 );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'my_restricted_page' );
```

Alternatively, you could just [set that page Visibility as Private](https://wordpress.org/support/article/content-visibility/) from the editor. The option is available under the “Publish” option normally found at the top-right of the Edit screen.